# Dynamic Formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a sheet called **Column Reo** on this sheet is a whole lot of data entry because on concrete column properties...

Eg:

1. width
2. depth
3. height
4. no. of vertical reinforcement bars
5. dia of bars

I also have a second sheet that has **fixed data** for some named rages etc on it...

Eg:

1. width
2. constants of reinforcement bars
3. ligature pattern type calcs

etc.

Each lig pattern needs a different formula based on shape of column and columns structural loading etc. There are 27 different lig pattern types.

I have written formulas on the "fixed data" sheet that would calculate the total length of each lig pattern based on the concrete columns properties and then created a drop down menu on the "column reo" sheet that uses **VLOOKUP** to match that up, problem is I want to drag across the actual formula so that it dynamically adjusts to the row that it's been copied to and uses the data from that row to calculate the total lig length.

I hope that explains it properly, I am hoping it can be done without VBA but if that is needed, so be it!

**EDIT**
Here is a link for the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/c29e0s4g13cr89p/Reo%20calculation%20sheet.xlsx

Based on the selection from "column reo"-H4 drop down menu I want to be able to pull across the formula from "fixed data" corresponding table. But I need the formula to adjust for the row that it is on.

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain but the formula for the column lig pattern is sitting in a data table eg: type 1 - formula 1, type 2 - formula 2... I want to use the value in the drop down menu (eg: Type 1) to copy cross the formula that corresponds to Type 1 but I need the rows value to adjust to suit the line it is on... Eg: there are 27 types so it might copied from row 15 off one sheet to row 120 on the other, I need the formula to pick up it's moved from row 15 to 120

Comment: please show us what the data in your "reo" sheet look like (post tabulated output of a small section) and post an example of one of the formulas you have on your calculations sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a dirty workaround without VBA, you could have all the types calculations as separate columns (in column reo sheet), then use the drop-down to pick which of these you want returned for that row... Ugly, but simple.

If you are happy to use VBA...

1. Enter your functions in your "fixed data" lookup as text (apostrophe at the start) like this `'=+(('column reo'!C<<row>>*2)+('column reo'!D<<row>>*2))+(('column reo'!C<<row>>/3*2)+('column reo'!D<<row>>*2))` (note that the row number in the formula is replaced with `<<row>>`
2. In VBA, create the function `calculateLig`:
   `Function calculateLig(r As Range) As Double`
   `Pattern = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(r, Application.Worksheets("fixed data").Range("J:K"), 2, 0)`
     `Pattern = Replace(Pattern, "<<row>>", r.Row)`
     `calculateLig = Evaluate(Pattern)`
   `End Function`
   This function does the `VLOOKUP` (hardcoded range - you could change that) to get back the text formula. It then replaces the keyword `<<row>>` in the formula with the row of the input cell and returns the evaluation of it. You can use this function as any other in your worksheet formula.

Answer (score 0):

My solution rellies on `EVAL()` function from Morefunc Addon*

1. Re-write your formulas on the `fixed data` sheet like shown below. Including the quotes - the cells are supposed to just store this as text, not actually perform any calculations:

   this is a new representation of your formula in K5 (to be pasted in L5):
   `"+((C"&ROW()&"*2)+(D"&ROW()&"4*2))+((C"&ROW()&"/3*2)+(D"&ROW()&"*2))"`
2. Make sure you have MORFUNC working (try writing `=Eval(" and see if it is recognised as a function
3. on `column reo` sheet write `=EVAL(EVAL(VLOOKUP(H4,'fixed data'!J4:L33,3,FALSE)))` in cell `K4`. This will check which "Col type" in selected in corresponding dropdown, and then use the new formulas to calculate corresponding "Lig Pattern"
4. repeat for other formulas on "fixed data" sheet, and copy-paste the formula on "column reo" sheet for all other lines.

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- Morefunc Addon is a free library of 66 new worksheet functions.
- [HERE](http://web.archive.org/web/20111204011358/http://xcell05.free.fr/morefunc/english) is some information (by original author)
- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)